# How to directly make use of JAR file from main resources folder Java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

This might be a slightly unusual question but I have a unique situation where something like this is a good solution for me.

I have a jar file (called engine.jar) within my src/main/resources. How can I directly make use of this jar from my main JAVA class? (add this in the build path?) but....

I have another JAR file (of the exact same name i.e. engine.jar) within my Maven Dependencies library which has slightly different code. I want to make use of this jar later on in my main class.

Comment: you shouldn't put jar files into `src/main/resources` or any sub folder in your maven project. It should be put into your repository manager and than you simply use it as a dependency as any other dependency.

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes that's true but as I mentioned, I have a unique situation. And this the the basis for my question

Comment: And what is so unique? Can you explain that why you have such sitution? Your setup sounds wrong...Is it for a test or what?

Comment: Yes for a test I want to run against my old and new engines, to ensure backwards compatibility

Comment: If you have a test than the jar file should be put into `src/test/resources` apart from that you have integration tests which means usually having a separate module in maven which contains the appropriate dependencies so no need for a jar file in resources folder...

Comment: It's not a unit test. It's an application with a static main method. It's purpose is to serve as a test of my engine. So it's resource (the jar file) should remain in 'src/main/resource'

Comment: Command line application? Could be tested with default JUnit and io stream redirection etc. ?

Comment: The tester app is a cmdline application, which tests my engine (the jar file). Junit may not be appropriate here

Answer (score 1):

The contents of Maven resource folders are copied to target/classes and from there to the root of the resulting Jar file. That is the expected behaviour.

What I don't understand is what the problem is in your scenario. Referencing a Resource through `getClass().getResource("/filename.txt")` starts at the root of the classpath, whether that (or an element of it) is `target/classes` or the JAR's root. The only possible error I see is that you are using the wrong `ClassLoader`.

Make sure that the class that uses the resource is in the same artifact (JAR) as the resource and do `ThatClass.class.getResource("/path/with/slash") or ThatClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/without/slash").`

But apart from that: if it isn't working, you are probably doing something wrong somewhere in the build process. Can you verify that the resource is in the JAR?

Comment: I have yet to write my top level class which makes use of the classes and methods inside the jar. I'm actually not sure I understand your solution though. The jar file is located at the root of src/main/resources. Are you saying that I can use .getResource and point directly to fully qualified classes within the jar file? 'com/company/engine/PrintEngine.java' How would my import statements look? import com.company.engine.PrintEngine.